# In Visual Studio "No quick actions available here" for "using" blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Several days ago, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> key combination, Visual Studio would suggest me to convert following code:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Raw request body:");
        sb.AppendLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
}
finally
{
    //.....
}
```

to this:

```
try
{
    using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true);
    sb.AppendLine("Raw request body:");
    sb.AppendLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}
finally
{
    //.....
}
```

But now it is showing "No quick actions available here". Other quick actions, like converting  implicit var type to explicit one etc., are still there.

What could happen? How to restore the original behavior?

Comment: What C# version are you targetting? Are you in the same project as you were a few days ago? Note that these days, your C# version depends on your Target Framework (unless explicitly overridden), so if you're now in a project which is targetting .NET Core 2.x / .NET Standard 2.0 or earlier, you'll be using C# 7.3, which doesn't have using declarations

Comment: how does the compiler know which lines are context of using, without the brackets?

Comment: Lei Yang: When the variable goes out of scope. In this case - try block.

Comment: @LeiYang - canton7 already gave you a hint in their comment when they referred to  [using declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration)

Comment: ok. so seems the only benefit is less typing two brackets.

Comment: canton7: It is a kind of black magic. Now it suddenly works again. I did nothing.

Comment: @Paul Sometimes things just take a while to load, and when they don't, VS tries to not sit there with a little progress spinner, so it shows you what it has

Comment: @LeiYang And you reduce a level of indentation. It particularly makes a difference when you have a number of nested `usings`, where you might save 2 or 4 levels of indentation

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: My problem solved itself. I didn't do anything for it.